# Call to window.print firing before documents style is applied

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a form with a print function. Inside the function I open a window, build the document, add the head with style sheets, add the form HTML and make the call to print the last part of the body. The problem is the initial print preview/print doesn't reflect the style. If I cancel the print and attempt to print manually, the style shows up. 
I've tried quite a few ways of doing this with no luck. It seems like a timing issue. Any ideas?

Browser is Chrome. Below is the JS function. (This is injected with a faces context).

```
function printForm(windowTitle, path){
    var printWindow = window.open();
    var printDocument = printWindow.document;

    var headHtml = "<link href='" + path + "/css/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>";

    printDocument.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML = headHtml;

    var printDiv = printDocument.createElement("DIV");
    var formDiv = document.getElementById("formDiv");

    printDiv.innerHTML = formDiv.innerHTML // Styling here is the issue
    printDocument.body.appendChild(printDiv);

    var scriptTag = printDocument.createElement("script");
    var script = printDocument.createTextNode("print();");
    scriptTag.appendChild(script);
    printDocument.body.appendChild(scriptTag);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a setTimeout to delay printing for a second or two so the style can be applied. You'll need to tinker to find the right length.

Comment: See my answer for a solution where you do not have to guess how long is correct for your css file.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to guessing with a timer, it might be more precise to use the `load` event on the `<link ...>` to know exactly when it has completed loading.

Below is a function I use which illustrates this technique.  It uses an off-screen `<iframe>` to print a portion of a page.  It's jQuery based, but the principles are the same in vanilla JS.  Note the setting of the `<link>'s` `onload` function with an anonymous function which invokes `print()` on the `<iframe>'s` window object.

```
/*
 * expects:
 *   <tag id="whatever">...goop...</tag>
 *   <input type="button" class="printit" data-target="whatever" value="Print">
 */
$(function() {
        $( '.printit' ).click(function() {
                var goop = $( '#' + this.dataset.target ).prop('outerHTML');
                var ifr = $('<iframe>');
                var bas = $('<base href="' + document.baseURI + '">');
                var lnk = $('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/print.css">');
                lnk.on('load', function() {                     /* CSS is ready! */
                        ifr[0].contentWindow.print();
                });
                ifr.css( { position: 'absolute', top: '-10000px' } )
                   .appendTo('body')
                   .contents().find('body').append(goop);
                ifr.contents().find('head').append(bas).append(lnk);
                return false;
        });
});
```